# Regular expression always get if there

Tags: python, regex, python-3.5

I have to parse a string with some text and possibly a url, separated by some whitespace, for example:

```
Hello, World! https://example.com/123456
Hello, World!
```

I tried

```
^(.*)\s(https://example\.com/.+)?$
```

but this ignores the url and puts it with the rest of the text if it finds it.

How can I change it so that it will always find the url if it's there?

Comment: Do you have to do it all at once, in a single regex like that?  Doing it in multiple steps may be easier...

Comment: `https://example\.com/.+` is the part that matches an url (altought you probably need `https://example\.com/[^ ]+` in your case), why do you need the other stuff around?

Comment: Works for me. How do you use it? What language/tool

Comment: Do you have trailing whitespace following your URL? That would cause URL to be matched by the greeding `.*`, instead of the optional URL portion.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the first term `.*` is *greedy*, and will consume all the input, leaving nothing left to match the URL. Use a *reluctant* quantifier `.*?` instead:

```
^(.*?)\s*(https://example\.com/.+)?$
```

I made the whitespace optional too, otherwise plain text would need to have trailing whitespace to match, which is not correct.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/5YCpDBSuq0).

Comment: The non-greedy match doesn't make a difference; the `\s` between the two groups is sufficient to stop the greedy match from including the URL as well, unless the string has trailing whitespace.

Comment: @chepner just looking at it, the whitespace being required would mean non-URL case wouldn't match unless it has trailing whitespace, which doesn't sound right. I've made the whitespace optional, which seems to work correctly in the demo link

Comment: Great. Then you should probably [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.